# Displaying table data in some column while looping

Tags: php

I want to show my database to table, but not just repeating in 1 row, I want it  repeating in 4 column. In this code, the table show :

No Kursi
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <tr> 
        <th ><strong>No Kursi</strong></th>   
      </tr>
        <?php
        $s = mysqli_query($koneksidb, "SELECT no_kursi FROM tkursi ORDER BY no_kursi ASC ");
     $nomor  = 1; 
        while ($kolomData = mysqli_fetch_array($s)) { 
        ?>
      <tr> 
        <td> <input type="radio" name="tambah3" value="O" required 
        <?php echo ($data7==$kolomData['no_kursi']) ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/>
        <label  class="inline" for="<?php echo $kolomData['no_kursi']; ?>">
        <?php echo $kolomData['no_kursi']; ?> &nbsp; </label> </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

I want my table show in every 4 column than next row:
      No kursi
01 02 03 04 
05 06 07 08 
09 10

Comment: just use that `$nomor` and use modulus in creating the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr> 
        <th ><strong>No Kursi</strong></th>   
    </tr>
    <?php
        $s = mysqli_query($koneksidb, "SELECT no FROM tkursi ORDER BY no_kursi ASC ");
        $nomor  = 1; 
        while ($kolomData = mysqli_fetch_array($s)) { 
    ?>
    <?php if($nomor%4 == 1){ ?>   
        <tr> 
    <?php } ?>

    <td> <input type="radio" name="tambah3" value="O" required 
    <?php echo ($data7==$kolomData['no_kursi']) ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/>
    <label  class="inline" for="<?php echo $kolomData['no_kursi']; ?>">
    <?php echo $kolomData['no_kursi']; ?> &nbsp; </label> </td>
    <?php if($nomor%4 == 0){ ?>   
        </tr>  
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 
        $nomor++;
    } ?>
</table>
```

Edited : It should be 2 equal signs `if($nomor%4 == 0)` .

Comment: I got no display, if I delete all related code:  if($nomor%4=1) it show corectly in 1 column. any more advise?

Comment: Sorry, I edited again, it should be 2 equal signs `==`